# Removing white spaces through padding of iframe in R shiny

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I am using the code below to remove white spaces that I generated through iframe:

```
output$table <- renderUI( {tags$iframe(src=paste0(AAA,"Title"), 
                          width='100%', 
                          height='1400px', 
                          padding = '0px',                  
                          style="display:block",
                          frameborder = "no",
                          seamless = TRUE)})
```

However, I am still seeing white spaces. How do I fix that?

Comment: Does your `iframe` still have margins around it?

Comment: No  margins around it